# Folder structure for express-typescript project

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want to know the best folder structure for typescript-express backend project.

Presently i am fallowing the bellow structure.

src-
  -controllers
  -models
  -middleware
  -utils

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am generally following this guide: https://gist.github.com/tracker1/59f2c13044315f88bee9

This can be applied to most javascript projects (nodejs or frontend-only) and is (kind of) used by a lot of CLIs like the vue and react cli.

Your controllers, models etc. should therefore be inside the SRC folder.